# python video b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\

Tags: python, video, websocket, opencv

i receive from websockets this video stream
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00....
i save the strea to file

> Blockquote

```
frame = await websocket.recv()
dataImg64 = str(frame)
with open("from_web.mp4", "wb") as f:
                f.write(stream)
                f.flush()
```

> Blockquote

the file from_web.mp4 contains
b'\x1aE\xdf\xa3\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00....

i try to open the from_web.mp4
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("da_email.mp4")
but i have the error

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x27cd9e0] moov atom not found
VIDIOC_REQBUFS: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

any suggestions?
Peter

Comment: 17 spaces for identation, really?

Comment: Are you "decrpyting" the data sent from the websockets? I mean websockets have a specific format to "encrypt" the message, are these the raw bytes or the decrypted ones?

Answer (score -1):

i re-write the part of code

```
frame = await websocket.recv()
stream= str(frame)##i made a cast to string, is right?
with open("from_web.mp4", "wb") as f:
            f.write(stream)
            f.flush()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("da_email.mp4")
```

Answer (score -1):

i have resolve, with this part of code
frame = await websocket.recv()

```
with open("from_web.mp4", "wb") as f:
        f.write(frame[0:len(frame)])
        f.flush()
```

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("da_email.mp4")